# How to add a UIButton at runtime

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am trying to add a `UIButton` at runtime however it is not visible. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25);
        btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [btn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btn.center = self.center;
        [self addSubview:btn];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: This code will leak; you're retaining your btn object, but never releasing it. The first retain message is unnecessary.

Comment: I've achieved good results with adding the UIButton view to the subview from viewDidLoad instead of some init methods.

Comment: Me too face the same problem. What was the actual issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, make sure the initWithFrame: method is being called. If your view is in a Nib, initWithCoder: is being called instead.

Second, is the button the only subview (from your code it looks like it is, but you never know). The button could be hidden behind another subview. Call bringSubviewToFront: if you need to.

Finally, is the view itself visible? Is it big enough to show the button? Given your example, if the view is less than 100 pixels wide, the button won't show because it will get clipped by the view's bounds.

Comment: So, what solved it? These are three possibilities... could you post the code that DID work?

Answer (score 1):

You must release `btn` and remove ":" in `buttonClick`:

```
UIButton *btn= [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25);
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[btn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:btn]; 
[btn release];
```

Comment: Saying to remove the : in 'buttonClick' is inappropriate. The default handlers are -(void)onClick:(id)sender . So, a ":" would be required. If the handler does not have an input, then yes. Alternative to releasing would be to autorelease the button in the create statement.

Answer (score 0):

if it still doesn't work, try removing the : at the end of the selector name: @selector(buttonClick)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to retain the UIButton because it is retained by [self.view addSubview:btn];

Comment: This isn't related to the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

First check whether your code is executing the initwithFrame method.
Because if you are loading the view from nib i.e using

```
NSArray *xibviews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"MySubview" owner: mySubview options: NULL];
MySubview *msView = [xibviews objectAtIndex: 0];
[self.view addSubview:msView];
```

Then the initWithFrame part will not be executing.So please check once.