# Array of Buttons

Tags: objective-c

for example, I need to create an array of buttons, which names are button1,button2...button10.
could you show me, how to add those 10 buttons to an array?

> for (int i = 0 ; i<=9; i++)
> {
> [myarray addObject:???];
>
> }

Thanks!

Comment: This question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307845/how-to-add-a-uibutton-at-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

int i = 0;
for (i=0;i<=9;i++) {
[myDictionary setObject:object forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"object%i",i]];
}
```

That will give you a dictionary with object0 - object9. The setObject parameter can be any object (NSString, NSNumber, NSArray).

Oh, and dont forget to

```
[myDictionary release];
```

When you are done with it. And to get things from the dictionary you would do this (if the object stored was an NSString):

```
NSString *myString = [myDictionary objectForKey@"object0"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can simply access an object in objective c by its name.  You'll probably have to create IBOutlets to each of the buttons and then add the pointers to an NSDictionary on init. A dictionary would act very similar to an array, so it's probably in your best interest to skip an array and just use NSDictionary so you can label the buttons with the "key".

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I still need a help, how to add buttons using a cycle.