# Create buttons from a text array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiwebview, uibutton

Sorry I can't think of a good title for this but here' my situation:
I have bunch of text in a UITextView, and I want some words to becomes buttons (the list of words can be in an array)...and basically, when the user clicks these buttons, it will push a uiviewcontroller on the nav controller displaying details about that word....

My main problem is: How can I make these select words buttons? What the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: This post should help you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307845...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307845/how-to-add-a-uibutton-at-runtime)

Comment: @Kyle I am not sure about that. How will he know the where the words are if he should put a button on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need editing of the text I suggest using a UIWebView and making those words links. Then implement the UIWebViewDelegate method: [`webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951-CH3-SW6) and catch clicking of a link with it. Then show your viewcontroller.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. I don't need to editing and I think this is the best choice. Thanks again.